# Qgis coordinate transformation

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

Sorry I'm a newbie with CRS

I have a shapefile (points) with coordinates in CRS EPSG:3854 (SRP) so that I can show the points within the open layers plugin.

Now I need to transform those points in EPSG:4326. The points do now have Long/Lat coordinates.

But i want to have them in E: and N:

e.g.

LAT: 53.376775 LONG: 9.288940

equals

E:3519305.232 N: 5916149.281

How can I transform them if I have many (like 100) points? Is there a fast way to do this?